# asp net regular expression for not allowing blank spaces

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, validation

I want my validator to not allowing the user to enter more then 1 blank space since my application will crash. And a maximum of 25 characters, what is the regex for this?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationGroup="grpSearch" ID="valSearch" ControlToValidate="txtSearchFor" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"/>
```

The expression I have tried there does not work.

Comment: Can the space appear at the end of string? It is clear from your pattern it cannot be at the start.

Comment: Yes after the string is fine, but not if there is nothing and user only blank spaces more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
ValidationExpression="^(?!.{26})[a-zA-Z0-9]+( [a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eFrwzF/2).

*Details*:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(?!.{26})` - no 26 chars allowed (25 and fewer only)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `( [a-zA-Z0-9]*)?` - optional group matching a space and 0+ alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string

Just in case it is of interest: to disallow the space at the end of string, the `*` quantifier (*zero* or more occurrences) should be replaced with the `+` quantifier (*one* or more occurrences).

Comment: This is weird, I can still enter multiple blank spaces. Why is that? Also, it does not allow the user to enter *. Which I want them to be able to!

Comment: You want the users to enter an asterisk? But you have no asterisk in your pattern. If you can enter more than 1 space, the issue is out there, the regex just does not allow that. To allow asterisks, just add it to the pattern: `"^(?!.{26})[a-zA-Z0-9*]+( [a-zA-Z0-9*]*)?$"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[^ ]+ [^ ]+$
```

This is of a similar theme, but asserts your requirement for alpha-numeric characters only:

```
^(A-Za-z0-9|[^ ])+ (A-Za-z0-9|[^ ])+$
```

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/3w6B6h/3